# Change the state of button to pressed

Tags: android, button, state

What I am trying to achieve: When the button is pressed for the first time, it should get highlighted/ activated / pressed. On the second click on the button it should get unactivated/ not pressed.
and later I want to check that if the button isPressed, do something.

What I tried:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.day_button:
        if (v.isPressed() == true) {
            v.setPressed(false);
        } else if (v.isPressed() == false) {
            v.setPressed(true);
        }
        return true;
```

I tried this with `day_but.isPressed == true` also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can use toggle button. For more info http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/togglebutton.html

```
<ToggleButton 
    android:id="@+id/togglebutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textOn="Vibrate on"
    android:textOff="Vibrate off"
    android:onClick="onToggleClicked"/>
```

or there is another approach you can follow. you can apply style in your button.

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     style="@button_style/<StyleName>"
     android:layout_width="200dp"
     android:layout_height="126dp"
     android:text="Hello" />
```

Create a button_style.xml file in drawable directory

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_selected" android:state_selected="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"></item>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/numpad_button_bg_normal"></item>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try with this way change the background state of button when click set the images as a background

```
Button testButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonTestButton);
int status = 0;//GLOBAL VARIABLE : the status of the Button ( 0 or 1 ) 
testButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //toggle picture
        if (status == 0) {
            testButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.alternatepicture);
            status=1 ; // change the status to 1 so the at the second clic , the else will be executed
        }   

        else {  
            testButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.fakpicture);
            status =0;//change the status to 0 so the at the second clic , the if will be executed
        }
    }//end void onClick

});
```

Answer (score 1):

XML CODE:

```
   <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/btspeaker"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bgspeaker"
            android:button="@null"
            android:textOff=""
            android:textOn="" />
```

In the drawable:

bgspeaker.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/speaker_btn_select" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/speaker_btn" android:state_checked="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/speaker_btn"></item>
</selector>
```

In the activity:

```
if (v.getId() == R.id.btspeaker) {
            if (btspeaker.isChecked()) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "Pressed/Selected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(context,"UnSelected",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also define a Selector for your Button to customize highlighting,so you create a xml file then :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_enabled="true"
      android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/enable_notpressed" />
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:state_enabled="true"
      android:drawable="@drawable/enable_pressed" />
<item android:state_pressed="false" android:state_enabled="false"
      android:state_focused="false" android:drawable="@drawable/disabled" />
</selector>
```

then assign it to your button as background param.

Answer (score 1):

use selector like:
  make a new xml file in drawable folder and paste this code.and change values accordingly.

```
        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="2dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item> 
 <item>
    <shape>
        <gradient
            android:startColor="#003040"
            android:endColor="#003040"
            android:angle="180" />
                    <corners
            android:radius="8dp" />

        <padding
            android:left="10dp"
            android:top="2dp"
            android:right="10dp"
            android:bottom="2dp" />
    </shape>
</item>

</selector>
```

!!happy coding!!